# requestMatcher permitAll() asking for authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following security config

```
return httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/registerUser/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

But both of the `http://localhost:8080/h2-console` and `http://localhost:8080/registerUser` endpoint asking for authentication.

```
.requestMatchers("/registerUser/").permitAll()
```

Does not work either.

I am using Spring security 6.

Any hints how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `antMatchers` instead of  `requestMatchers`:

```
httpSecurity
.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .antMatchers("/registerUser/**", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated());
```